# How to Ratelimit a URL path with wagtail?

Tags: python, django, redis, wagtail, rate-limiting

I am in the process of migrating an existing django project to use wagtail CMS.

I am unclear how I can ratelimit using wagtail, I see nothing about it in the documentation.

Take the following example:

Before integrating wagtail, I had a view which would return a privacy policy html page. This was ratelimited using redis, you can see the method decorator and method below

```
@ratelimit(
    key='ip',
    rate='15/m',
    block=True
)
def show_privacy_policy(request):
    context = base_context(request)
    return render(
        request,
        'pages/privacy_policy.html',
        context
    )
```

Now this is removed, and I have a more generic wagtail Page which is used to render pages such as terms and conditions or privacy policy, I call this an `InfoPage`. The only thing I have defined is my InfoPage model which has a template path attached `wagtail/info_page.html`.

```
class InfoPage(Page):

    template = "wagtail/info_page.html"
    last_modified_date = models.DateField("Last modified date")
    body = RichTextField(features=['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'ul', 'h3'])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('last_modified_date'),
        FieldPanel('body')
    ]
    
    parent_page_types = ['news.Index']
    subpage_types = []
```

This simply just works, and all of my InfoPages are rendered correctly. However, I do not see any way to ratelimit access to these pages. If there is no way to ratelimit, I am susceptible to DDOS attacks and more. What am I missing here? Is there a way to ratelimit access or do I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Wagtail page objects implement [a `serve` method](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) that behaves in the same way as a Django view, accepting a request object and returning a response. The `@ratelimit` decorator could most likely be applied here. However, this probably won't be very effective, since Wagtail has to perform a number of database queries just to find out which page corresponds to a given URL - by the time you've arrived at a page object, the request has already consumed a non-trivial amount of server resources.

I would recommend applying rate limiting at the web server level - for example, see [the Nginx documentation on rate limiting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) - or externally using a service such as Cloudflare, as @cnk suggests. These options will almost certainly be more security-hardened and better-performing than anything done at the Django / Python application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rate limit, I would suggest using a frontend cache so it is cheap to serve the rendered page. I use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) with the built-[enter link description here](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/frontendcache.html)in cache invalidator. There are a number of cache invalidators included with the stock Wagtail distro or you could use [wagtail-cache](https://docs.coderedcorp.com/wagtail-cache/) from [CodeRed](https://www.codered.cloud/).